# What does "routes" mean? [Netplan, YAML file]

Tags: networking, command-line, netplan

Here's an example I've taken from somewhere:

```
routes:
    - to: default
      via: 10.225.192.1
```

I've seen that this syntax has replaced the "gateway4", however, I've searched for infomation about the concept "route" and seems to be different from "gateway".

Here is what I know:

- **gateway**: It is the ip of the device that allows us to connect to other networks.
- **route**: It is the path that a package takes to go from computer "A" to computer "B".

So...

1. Are my definitions right?
2. How is the concept of "route" applied in the syntax?
3. Could you explain me the syntax?

Note: I've assumed that what goes next to "via" had to be the ip what would go in the gateway, but "to: default"? I'm not sure what its function is.

Comment: Did you Google what a route is in networking?

Comment: Yes, the definition I've written on the question is what I've understood. So I'm asking because I still don't understand how it is applied in the syntax of the yaml file.

Comment: You could just look at some of the other sites the search produces till you understand.

Answer (score 1):

The [Netplan reference](https://netplan.io/reference#routing) has information on this.

> ### Default routes
>
> The most common need for routing concerns the
> definition of default routes to reach the wider Internet. Those
> default routes can only defined once per IP family and routing table.

The Netplan reference is the de facto standard for understanding the Netplan syntax.

The default route is also commonly referred to as default gateway (hence the Netplan property `gateway`, which is now replaced by default route as in your example).

If you want to learn more about networking terminology, Ask Ubuntu probably isn't the most obvious place. You could start on Wikipedia though ([Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing) and [Default route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_route)).

Comment: Many people are confusing gateway with router. Even many IT folks. There is a definitive difference between a gateway and a router. A gateway is per definition a device which is able to translate network protocols into other network protocols. A router is a device which forwards/sends IP packages from/to the correct network segment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your definitions are correct, but it is a little confusing how they relate here. The way I understand it, `routes` is a list of addresses and how to get to them. e.g.

```
routes:
  - to: default # This matches any address
    via: 10.225.192.1 # Your default gateway (to get to `default`, use this route)

  - to: 192.168.0.0 # This is a specific set of addresses
    via: 10.225.192.2 # A different router that knows how to get to _this_ subnet
```